# Is this simplification correct, and if so, what law does it illustrate?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can I simplify

$(F \land \neg M )
\lor
(F \land A)
\lor
(F \land M \land G)$

to

$F \land (\neg M \lor A \lor (M \land G) )$

?
And if so, what law does this illustrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\color{blue}{F} \land \neg M )
\lor
(\color{blue}{F} \land A)
\lor
(\color{blue}{F} \land M \land G)$

We can use the **distributive law** to get:

$\color{blue}{F} \land (\neg M \lor A \lor (M \land G) )$  You can simplify by first using commutativity of disjunction to obtain $$F \land( A \lor\lnot M \lor(M\land G))$$ and then $$F\land (A \lor((\lnot M\lor M) \land (\lnot M \lor G))$$

Which can be simplified to

$$F\land (A \lor \lnot M \lor G))$$

Comment: The transition from top expression, using distributivity of And over Or.  Then after commuting I distribute Or over And

Answer (score 1):

The distributive law is the factoring law. You have factorised the expression by taking out the common factor of F.

So it is the distributive law.

Comment: Over at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), I'm reading about two kinds of distributivity: Distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$ (similar to ordinary algebra), and distributivity of $\lor$ over $\land$ (not like ordinary algebra).  Which one of these (or both) are in use in this OP?

Comment: Both are in use.